# IOS:Questions about AudioQueue

Tags: ios, swift, audioqueue

Who can tell me what “`kAudioQueueProperty_TimePitchAlgorithm`” means in detail?

When I use `audioqueue` for fast forward or fast backward, I find that the speed between 0.9 and 1.25 is invalid when I do not set the property `kAudioQueueProperty_TimePitchAlgorithm`.

```
propValue = 1;
AudioQueueSetProperty(audioQueueRef,kAudioQueueProperty_TimePitchBypass, &propValue, sizeof(propValue));
propValue = kAudioQueueTimePitchAlgorithm_Spectral;
AudioQueueSetProperty(audioQueueRef, kAudioQueueProperty_TimePitchAlgorithm, &propValue, sizeof(propValue));
```

When I set the property `kAudioQueueProperty_TimePitchAlgorithm`, the speed between 0.9 and 1.25 takes effect.